# How to make the mesh not bumpy? On subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling

How to make the mesh not bumpy? (Like the images below) It has subsurf modifiers and adding loop cut isn't work anyone know how to handle it thanks

[image]

Comment: Ok much thanks for respond

Answer (score 0):

You must have a ngon at the top, you need to inset once or twice:

[image]

Comment: Ok much thanks for respond